# How to kill Node.js child process using pid?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am looking for a way to kill Node.js processes using their pid. I've been searching Google, StackOverflow, and the Node.js documentation for hours. It seems like something that should exist. I can only find how to do it based on my variable `newProc` below, but I cannot do `newProc.kill()` because I want to kill the child process from outside of the function scope. Additionally, I need to store something in MongoDB for record-keeping purposes, so I thought pid would be more appropriate.

```
var pid = newJob();
kill(pid); //<--anything like this?

var newJob = function () {
  var exec = require('child_process').exec,
  var newProc = exec("some long running job", function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log("stdout: " + stdout);
    console.log("stderr: " + stderr);
    if (error) console.log('exec error: ' + error);
  });
  return newProc.pid;
}
```

EDIT: Can I use `process.kill(pid)` on a child process? The [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_kill_pid_signal) state that it is a global object that can be accessed from anywhere.

Finally, as a slight tangent, is there a way to ensure that the pid's will always be unique? I don't want to unintentionally kill a process, of course.

Comment: Why can't you `return newProc` and then call `newProc.kill('SIGHUP');`. Also you can spawn a more linux like `exec('kill -9 ' + newProc.pid, callback);`

Comment: I need to store something in MongoDB for record-keeping purposes, so I thought pid would be more appropriate. Should I simply store `newProc` in MongoDB and then call `newProc.kill('SIGHUP');` on it later? If that doesn't work, I'll try your second suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[process.kill()](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_kill_pid_signal) does the job. As said in your edit, `process` is a global object available in every Node module.

Note that the PID only uniquely identifies your child process as long as it is running. After it has exited, the PID might have been reused for a different process. If you want to be really sure that you don't kill another process by accident, you need some method of checking whether the process is actually the one you spawned. (`newProc.kill()` is essentially a wrapper around `process.kill(pid)` and thus has [the same problem](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_kill_signal).)

Comment: In doc's example it's not showing how to to use a pid to kill the process. We need to use the spawned reference to send  `spawned.kill([signal])`. I was wishing to finish a child process using pid number, assuming I'm sure that it's a child process. Is there a way to do that without another library?

Comment: @LeonardoRick Check the documentation of `process.kill()` again. Its signature is `process.kill(pid, [status])`, so if killing a process by PID is what you're after, this is your function.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the module "tree-kill".

```
var kill  = require('tree-kill');
var exec  = require('child_process').exec;

  var child = exec('program.exe',  {cwd: 'C:/test'}, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (stdout) console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
        if (stderr) console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
        if (err !== null) {
          console.log('exec error: ' + err)};
    });
  child.stdout.on('data', function(log_data) {
      console.log(log_data)
  });

kill(child.pid);
```

This kill you child process by it PID for sure ;-)

Comment: I love love love love love love  you

Answer (score 0):

use tree-kill module and pass the id as process.pid which kills the processes which are long and **doesn't return**.

```
const kill  = require('tree-kill');
const exec  = require('child_process').exec;

exec("some long non-return job like server start", function (error, stdout, stderr) {
console.log("stdout: " + stdout);
console.log("stderr: " + stderr);
if (error) console.log('exec error: ' + error);
});       
kill(process.pid);
```